# App signing of existing APK, what about SHA1 keys?

Tags: android, android-app-bundle, android-app-signing

When we migrate the app which uses Firebase, Adjust, Fabric and Insider to App Signing and App Bundle, should we update our SDK SHA1 keys or not? I am confused about these and I can't find answer of these.

Fabric is not using aab right now. How can we workaround that kind of situations?

Answer (score 0):

Google Play will use the same keystore which you have used before when you initially published your app to the Google Play Store. It will even require you to do so, otherwhise you won't be able to let Android devices update to a newer version of your app, since the signatures will not match.

When creating an Android App Bundle, (.aab), you will sign it with your current keystore which you have used before. It will generate the .aab and if you want, it will also generate a publish key which the Google Play Developer Console needs to resign your app.

> should we update our SDK SHA1 keys or not?

No, just figure out the signature sha1 of your signed APK bundle, then it will work fine. Even when using .aab's. When Google resigns your app, the sha1 will still match.

Answer (score 0):

No, you shouldn't update you SDKs SHA1 keys for apps already existing in Google Play Console, since your bundle will be signed by the same keys as your APK.

Here is info about enrolling into App Signing for already released apps: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#enroll_existing

As to Fabric Beta not supporting AABs - you should switch to Firebase App Distribution, which became available recently. It supports AABs and this is an actual replacement for Fabric Beta from the Firebase team.

Here is some info about it: https://firebase.google.com/products/app-distribution